# Live Templates in WebStorm per project (via .idea folder)..?

Tags: ide, webstorm, code-snippets

I know we can create Live Templates in the settings, and group them, but we would like to have a set of Live Templates on a per project basis.

In VS Code, you can create `code-snippets` files in the `.vscode` folder, and those snippets follow the project, so anyone who clones that project will get those project-specific snippets.

Is the any way to put Live Template xml files in the `.idea` folder and have WebStorm pick them up..?

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to save project Live Templates. Feel free to file a feature request on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks! As the answer below points out, there is a 13 year old one for this already... Fingers crossed, any day now.... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project-level live templates are not supported currently; please vote for [IDEABKL-5033](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5033) to be notified on any progress with this feature request

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not the only one then.  However..... That is 13 years old isn't it..?  :-o